# Gulp.js stops compiling LESS when watched after there has been an error in the LESS files

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-less

I'm having a problem with `gulp`. I run `gulp-watch` along with `gulp-less` and `gulp-clean`. Everything is running perfectly.

When I edit `somefile.less` and I save it with a semi-colon missing or maybe I accidentally leave a trailing `;s`, just have errors in my code when saving, `gulp-less` logs an error in the console. After I fix it `gulp-watch` continues watching the files, but `gulp-less` doesn't fire and it doesn't compile. When I stop `gulp` and run it again in the terminal everything goes back to normal.

Here is my `gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var clean = require('gulp-clean');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var path = require('path');

gulp.task('clean', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/main/webapp/styles/build', {read: false})
   .pipe(clean().on('error', gutil.log))
});

gulp.task('less', function() {
    return gulp.src(['src/main/webapp/styles/main.less'], {base: 'src/main/webapp/styles/'})
    .pipe(less().on('error', gutil.log))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/main/webapp/styles/build'))
    .on('error', gutil.log);
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    watch('src/main/webapp/styles/**/*.{less, css}', function() {
        gulp.start('less')
        .on('error', gutil.log);
    })
});

gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function() {
    gulp.start(['less', 'watch'])
    .on('error', gutil.log);
});
```

And here are my `devDependencies`:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.8.10",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.1",
    "gulp-less": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.2",
    "gulp-watch": "^3.0.0"
}
```

Finally, here is the message in the console:

```
[10:21:03] imports/productSearchPage.less was changed
[10:21:03] Starting 'less'...
[10:21:03] { [Error: Unrecognised input. Possibly missing something in file /src/main/webapp/styles/imports/productSearchPage.less line no. 1008]
  type: 'Parse',
  filename: '/src/main/webapp/styles/imports/productSearchPage.less',
  index: 19127,
  line: 1008,
  callLine: NaN,
  callExtract: undefined,
  column: 0,
  extract: [ '', '', undefined ],
  message: 'Unrecognised input. Possibly missing something in file /src/main/webapp/styles/imports/productSearchPage.less line no. 1008',
  stack: undefined,
  lineNumber: 1008,
  fileName: '/src/main/webapp/styles/imports/productSearchPage.less',
  name: 'Error',
  showStack: false,
  showProperties: true,
  plugin: 'gulp-less',
  __safety: { toString: [Function] } }
[10:21:04] imports/productSearchPage.less was changed
[10:21:08] imports/productSearchPage.less was changed
^C
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong with the `gulp-watch` task and help me make it run `gulp-less` after the errors have been removed, without restarting `gulp`.

EDIT:
My edited `gulp-less` task

```
gulp.task('less', function() {
    return gulp.src(['src/main/webapp/styles/main.less'], {base: 'src/main/webapp/styles/'})
    .pipe(less().on('error', gutil.log))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/main/webapp/styles/build'))
    .on('error', function(err) {
        gutil.log(err);
        this.emit('end');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It works now! Here is my final, and working, `gulp-less` task:

```
gulp.task('less', function() {
    return gulp.src(['src/main/webapp/styles/main.less'], {base: 'src/main/webapp/styles/'})
    .pipe(less().on('error', function(err){
        gutil.log(err);
        this.emit('end');
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/main/webapp/styles/build'))
});
```

The problem was that, when there was an error in the `LESS` the task still went on and built the destination file. On top of that I placed the error logging function and the `emit('end')` as a callback to `gulp.dest`.

Now, when the callback of `less()` is the error log and `emit('end')` everything works perfectly.

Comment: This bit got the less to rewatch for me  this.emit('end'). Thanks for your post!

Answer (score 2):

I always use [gulp-plumber](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-plumber) for my error catching. Works really easily and logs the error to the console.

Example:

```
gulp.task('less', function() {
    return gulp.src(['src/main/webapp/styles/main.less'], {base: 'src/main/webapp/styles/'})
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(less().on('error', gutil.log))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/main/webapp/styles/build'))
    .on('error', function(err) {
        gutil.log(err);
        this.emit('end');
    });
});
```

Comment: I use this too. It catches errors in the stream, before they have a chance to break it.

Answer (score 0):

I have just set this up for my own personal project. According to the [Gulp docs](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp), you can just use `gulp.watch`:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('src/main/webapp/styles/**/*.{less, css}', ['less'])
        .on('error', gutil.log);
});
```

EDIT: If this doesn't help, change your `less` task to:

```
gulp.task('less', function() {
    return gulp.src(['src/main/webapp/styles/main.less'], {base: 'src/main/webapp/styles/'})
    .pipe(less())
    .on('error', function (err) {
        gutil.log(err);
        this.emit('end');
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/main/webapp/styles/build'))
    .on('error', gutil.log);
});
```

Adapted from [this comment](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/259#issuecomment-55098512).

Comment: If this answer works, my answer was adapted from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905875/gulp-run-is-deprecated-how-do-i-compose-tasks

Comment: The problem stays. Also, `gulp-util` doesn't log the error to the console.

Comment: @PavelKuts - I think I've found your problem. See my updated answer.

Comment: See my edited question to see my new gulp task.

`gulp-less` now works after the error, but the error isn't logged to the console.

Comment: Your edited file doesn't contain my suggestion - what has changed?

Comment: I added `this.emit(end);`

Comment: You have a double closing parenthesis.
Besides that, the code doesn't log errors to the console, `gulp-less` works after there has been an error and is edited.
It still doesn't work.

Comment: Oops! Made one more minor change: should be `this.emit('end')`, with the 'end' being a string.

Comment: I will mark the answer as correct, as it does run the `gulp-less` task after there has been an error. But it would be nice to see a resolution where the errors are logged to the console. With the current code there are no logs.

Comment: Yeah, that's weird. I'm using almost identical code in one of my projects and I get all the logs... I hope you figure it out - good luck! :)

Comment: I figured it out, not without help from you! Check the edit in my question to see where I was failing, and hopefully you can use the code in the future. Cheers!

Comment: Ah, yes! Should've made it clearer - your .on('error'...) needs to come immediately after the .pipe(less()). Glad to hear you sorted it out!

Answer (score 0):

the best solution I have tried;
https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/combining-streams-to-handle-errors.md

```
var combiner = require('stream-combiner2');
gulp.task('multi:less', function(done) {
    var combined = combiner.obj([
        gulp.src(srcs),
        less(),
        autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 6 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }),
        isDev ? null : cleanCss(),
        gulp.dest(targetDir + 'css/multi/'),
    ].filter(v => v));

    // any errors in the above streams will get caught
    // by this listener, instead of being thrown:
    combined.on('error', console.error.bind(console));
    combined.on('end', () => {}); //done have been call when return combined;
    return combined;

}
```