# Gulp-imports, did not generate new file

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-imports

I'm using [Gulp-imports](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-imports/) to combine my library / vendor files into 1 file. https://github.com/ifandelse/gulp-imports

I believe I have it setup correctly, originally I got an error saying [gulp.run was deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905875/gulp-run-is-deprecated-how-do-i-compose-tasks), so I switched to using gulp.watch instead:

```
gulp.watch('app/assets/js/libs/vendors.min.js', function() {
    console.log('Combining vendor files');
    return gulpImports().pipe(gulp.dest('./min'));
});
```

It seems to run fine, however the return doesn't complete the process and generate a new `vendors.min.js` inside of a `/min` folder.

[image]

[image]

I run `gulp watch` and my normal CSS and JS tasks work, and I see the console.log statement for the gulp-imports, but no combined file...

---

Thanks to the answer below, this is what I used, I did not use `gulp.run`

```
gulp.task('imports', function() {
gulp.src(['./app/assets/js/libs/shizz.js'])
    .pipe(gulpImports())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./result/'));
});
```

What the shizz.js file looks like:

```
//import("angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js");
//import("angular-route/angular-route.min.js");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example [here](https://github.com/ifandelse/gulp-imports) suggests you're meant to `gulp.src` some files before piping into `gulpImports()`.

Comment: Ah thanks! Yeah I got it to work :) I ended up using `gulp-concat` for my project, but now this works as well too! Will update my question with what I used...